# .exe does not work on another PC "ctypes"

Tags: python, exe

I’ve recently tried making an .exe from my .py file.
(This is my first time making a .exe)

It’s a long script and includes [this](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576786-detect-when-system-is-idle/) cool function.
If I compile [this](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576786-detect-when-system-is-idle/) to a .exe
It works just fine on the PC I code on, but not on another PC. Which makes me believe there is something missing during the pip installer ?

To compile this script I need to have [ctypes](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32-ctypes/) Installed,
and in the cmd say: pyinstaller filename.py
Am I missing something ?

I don't have any error to show unfortunately, it just stays blank after it tries to run wait_until_idle.

Comment: ```this``` and the other ```this``` both link to the same thing

Comment: @Kareem Emad Ah sorry for the confusion, but I was talking about the same thing

Answer (score 1):

The most trusted/automated way that I found to make an exe out of python code is this package:

https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/

I tested it myself on multiple situations with whole projects not just single/small scripts.

The main disadvantage of this is the size of the exe file, it's really big and specially if you are using external libraries like `pandas`, `numpy` could easily make your exe pass 100 Mega bytes.

It's a simple graphical UI that you could use to generate exe, There is no external dependencies  you need to install separately.

Comment: I'll give it a go. Thanks

Comment: @ Kareem Emad unfortunately using this gives the same result

Comment: Let me try this myself, my first suspect is that you are trying to use windows specific libs on Linux, so autopy-to-exe  cannot build the target exe correctly. I will let you know what I find

Comment: could you try that ?
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CfUTbRX59j0GgyR0-EZ8Uib4dsXo9DiF/view?usp=sharing

I think it's working but I'm not sure what's the final outcome of your program so I cannot judge it by first print

Comment: I very much appreciate the help!
Im working on a windows machine, the .exe supposed to close after 10 seconds of no user input.
The version you send is the same unfortunately, it works on the PC I write code on, but not on a different PC.

Comment: Just to clarify: the exe I provided works on your own machine but does not work on someone else's ?

Comment: Maybe If you provide  more details in your post about the  OS specs of the target machine that fails, it will help narrowing down the issue.

Comment: @Kereem Emad I decided to re-write the whole code I was using (from the link), In such a way I didn't need to use ctypes. Its working perfect now. and thank you for the help along the way, stay safe ;)